# When I set my bool new_block to FALSE, the code does nothing (C)

Tags: c

I'm building a tetris game in C and and I have a `boolean` that controls whether I should deploy a new block. I used the following typedef to create the `bool` variable. When I run the program (`int main()`), after initialization, my program goes into an infinite while loop which is pretty much the game. For some reason, I have a line `new_block = FALSE;` that when not commented out, stops my program from doing anything. This is including the test `printf` statements I have put before it and after it. I can't figure out what's wrong with this simple statement? Thanks :)

```
typedef enum
{
    FALSE,
    TRUE
} bool;

while(1) {
    if (new_block) {
        printf("test1");
        i = 1;
        //i = rand() % 7;
        block = all_blocks[(i-1)*4];
        block.x = 5;
        block.y = 0;
        new_block = FALSE;
        printf("test2");
        //update_stack(tetris_stack, block, i);
        printf("test");
    }
}
```

I have checked and the print statements work fine when `new_block = FALSE;` is commented out so the error isn't in my block structure though I have added that below for reference.

```
typedef struct {
int x;
int y;
int block_no;
int rotation;
int other_x[3];
int other_y[3];
int up_check_no;
int up_x[3];
int up_y[3];
int left_rotate;
int right_rotate;
int down_rotate;
int max_left;
int left_check_no;
int left_x[4];
int left_y[4];
int max_right;
int right_check_no;
int right_x[4];
int right_y[4];
int max_down;
int down_check_no;
int down_x[4];
int down_y[4];
}block;
```

Comment: Please create a [MCVE](/help/mcve). Your code should compile.

Comment: Don't define homebrew boolean types, less with te name `bool`. C has a built-in boolean type and a standard header for the name `bool` plus macros for the constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the look of it, when you say:

```
new_block = FALSE;
```

the if statement:

```
 if (new_block)
```

will fail over and over and over again and your program will essentially hang forever. You probably want to have another conditional in your if statement or have an else statement or something to catch the case when creating a new block is false.

Comment: I get what you are saying but why would that occur? Isn't C code sequential (line by line)? When I initialized new_block (outside the while loop), I set it to TRUE. It was supposed to be a flag but if I need another variable it kind of defeats the purpose

Comment: So I tried "new_block = TRUE;" and it seems to fix things for some reason. Does anyone have any other way of creating a flag? I figured boolean would be the easiest way

Comment: The way you created the flag is just fine, but when the condition in the if statement fails (i.e. when new_block is false), you don't have code that does anything. You simply test to see if new_block is false, and if it is, you jump back up to your while loop and test again. What do you want to do when new_block is false?

Comment: if the new_block is false, I won't create a new block and i will continue with the game with the previously existent block.

Comment: Hey, I sort of got a temporary fix. I just changed the new_block outside of the if loop and carried on with other things. I still clueless why my previous code didn't work though. Thank for your help though!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you got it fixed!